# automatically query Facebook pages and store results in dict

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I have a list of facebook pages' names

```
pages = ['financialtimes', 'dailytelegraph', 'theguardian']
```

I want to store the names of these in a dict automatically; I already have the below function to question them but don't know how to get the results in a dictionary

```
app_id = "my_app_id"
app_secret = "my_app_secret"
access_token = app_id + "|" + app_secret

def FacebookIDs(page_name, access_token=access_token):
    """ get page's numeric information """  
    # construct the URL string
    base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4"
    node = "/" + str(page_name)
    parameters = "/?access_token=%s" % access_token
    url = base + node + parameters
    # retrieve data    
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode()) 
    print(data)
```

Comment: If you are doing some scraping on those pages, I recommend using `BeautifulSoup4` API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just one line of code changed in your function:

```
import json
def FacebookIDs(page_name, access_token=access_token):
    """ get page's numeric information """  
    # construct the URL string
    base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4"
    node = "/" + str(page_name)
    parameters = "/?access_token=%s" % access_token
    url = base + node + parameters
    # retrieve data    
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode()) 
    return data #change only this line
```

Change the last line, as indicated. Then define an empty dictionary and iterate over the list, defining the key as the list item and the value as the result of the function. (The returned JSON has two entries, so you need to select the entry `id`.)

```
pages_ids_dict = {}
for page in pages:
    pages_ids_dict[page] = FacebookIDs(page, access_token)['id']
```